# Can I specify the sub path of a Git repo to require in Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I want to use master version of [grpc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc)'s Ruby gem in my project. But it's located in `grpc/src/ruby`. So I can't just use it with `gem 'grpc', github: 'grpc/grpc'`.

Is there a solution to add the gem with something like this `gem 'grpc', github: 'grpc/grpc', sub_path: 'src/ruby'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about cloning the Gem repo to your local machine or the server and add it through the `path` option?

Like so:

```
gem 'grpc', path: 'path/to/your/local_repo'
```

I see there is an active issue about the same thing you are asking about on the Bundler Github repo<sup>[1]</sup>

[1] https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/396

Comment: I plan to do this. But you know, it's difficult to keep the code up-to-date when upstream changes. And I ask the maintainers to separate the ruby code into a individual repo in this issue https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/1156 . btw, thank you and the issue you give is helpful.

Comment: I am wondering if I want to use just the ActiveRecord from the upstream master branch how would I do that, it's the exact same scenario you are having. You know it's under the Rails repo. https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord

Comment: Try this [Gemfile man](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html#BLOCK-FORM-OF-GIT-PATH-GROUP-and-PLATFORMS). But it seems not support more than one level of directory